# Can you use App Configuration service with API Management instead of NVPs?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to make my ARM templates that I'm generating by the APIM Resource Kit as generic as possible to promote API changes, etc. through Dev/QA/Prod environments.

The way I've found to set back end endpoints per environment is by name/value pairs via policies.  It occurred to me doing this through the App Configuration instead of NVPs would allow me to make this more generic in the ARM templates.  Does anyone know if there's a way to do this or can point in me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out in the APIM resource kit, the serviceUrlParameters paramater for the extractor tool will handle generating out the files needed to make the backend endpoints configurable.